# Unsure how to NOT include a match in REGEXREPLACE

Tags: google-sheets

How do I turn **Bay 13 | Brand PS/CPP** into **13** using REGEXREPLACE in Google Sheets?
I can't figure out how to NOT include a pattern, as it seems whatever I type as the pattern it takes it out completely. I'm not used to this behavior in REGEX.

For instance:

```
REGEXREPLACE("(?i)bay ", )
```

returns **13 | Brand PS/CPP**.
I want to keep the 13 (which could be any number between 1-35 including halves (12.5)), and get rid of everything after it including the "|" pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `REGEXEXTRACT` here rather than `REGEXREPLACE`:

```
REGEXEXTRACT("\d+(?:\.\d+)?", "Bay 13 | Brand PS/CPP")
```

Comment: Consider the simpler `"[\d.]+"`.

Answer (score 1):

try "everything after bay and before a pipe":

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(?i)bay (.+) \|")
```

[image]

or if you want specifics:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(?i)bay (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) \|")
```

[image]